# Why are generics erased in arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I know that generic type information is erased at compile time in Java and therefore one cannot create arrays of generic types (because then at runtime it would not be possible to effectively enforce the types inserted into the array).
But why not make an exception? Why not just leave the generic type information for arrays (and only for them)?

What was the design decision behind this? In my opinion it would make life easier, it would be possible to do this.

```
T[] genericArray = new T[10];
```

Comment: Backward compatibility probably?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @BendeguzNagy I am not sure what advantage you would get from saying `T[] genericArray = new T[10];` vs using `Object[] genericArray = new Object[10]` in case of arrays. The type parameter is pretty much useless (unless you are expecting that once you add an element to `T[] genericArray `, the compiler should deduce the type and not let you added elements that are not of the type of the first element inserted? Ofcourse that's not possible and too much to ask for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**

It's because generics is metadata to help the compiler help you catch type
errors and everything is compiled to use the lowest common denominator
(usually `Object`) and type casts. This isn't done with arrays since arrays
are their own classes. I.e. An `ArrayList<String>` and an `ArrayList<Number>`
both have the class `ArrayList`, but an array of `String` has class `String[]` and an array of
`Number` has class `Number[]`.

**Long answer:**

When compiled, everything that is using generics will be using the least
common denominator (which is commonly `Object`). This is demonstrated by the
following code:

```
public class Generics {

    public static <T> void print(T what) {
        System.out.println(what);
    }

    public static <T extends Number> void printNumber(T what) {
        System.out.println(what);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(Generics.class.getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.getName().startsWith("print"))
                .forEach(Generics::print);
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
public static void Generics.print(java.lang.Object)
public static void Generics.printNumber(java.lang.Number)
```

So we can see that when it's compiled it is compiled as methods that works on `Object` and `Number` respectively.

This is the reason something like this will compile and run:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
ArrayList<Object> list2 = (ArrayList<Object>)(Object)list;
list2.add(Integer.valueOf(10));
System.out.println(list2.get(0));
System.out.println(list2.get(1));
```

If you try that you'll see that it prints

```
foo
10
```

So by the down/up-cast we turned our `ArrayList<String>` into an `ArrayList<Object>` - which wouldn't be possible if the ArrayList was actually storing it's contents in an array of type `String[]` instead of `Object[]`.

Note that trying to do

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
System.out.println(list.get(1));
```

Will result in a `ClassCastException`. And this hints at exactly what the
compiler does.

Look at the following code:

```
public static void doThingsWithList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("");
    String s = list.get(0);
    print(s);
}
```

When compiled, it's turned into this bytecode:

```
public static void doThingsWithList();
  Code:
     0: new           #11                 // class java/util/ArrayList
     3: dup
     4: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
     7: astore_0
     8: aload_0
     9: ldc           #13                 // String
    11: invokevirtual #14                 // Method java/util/ArrayList.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    14: pop
    15: aload_0
    16: iconst_0
    17: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/util/ArrayList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
    20: checkcast     #16                 // class java/lang/String
    23: astore_1
    24: aload_1
    25: invokestatic  #17                 // Method print:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    28: return
```

As you can see on line `20` the result from `ArrayList.get` is actually cast to `String`.

So generics is just syntactic sugar that turns into automatic type casting with the added benefit that the compiler can use this syntactic sugar to detect code that would result in a `ClassCastException` during runtime.

Now, why can't the compiler do the same for `String[]` and `Object[]`?  Couldn't it just turn

```
public <T> T[] addToNewArrayAndPrint(T item) {
    T[] array = new T[10];
    array[0] = item;
    System.out.println(array[0]);
    return array;
}
```

into

```
public <T> T[] addToNewArrayAndPrint(T item) {
    Object[] array = new Object[1];
    array[0] = item;
    System.out.println((T) array[0]);
    return array;
}
```

?

Nope. Because that would mean that

```
Arrays.equals(addToNewArray("foo"), new String[]{ "foo" });
```

would be false because the first array would have class `Object[]` and the second would have class `String[]`.

Sure, Java could be changed so that all arrays are of type `Object[]` and that all accesses would use casts, just as when using generics. But that would break backwards compatibility whereas using Generics doesn't since an `ArrayList<String>` has the same class as an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a construct like `new T[10];` is that `T` could be anything, including `Void` (which is actually an uninstantiable class and would generate a compilation error).

If you think about it, types are a language construct and therefore should make its magic at compile time, rather than at runtime. There are situations in which it would make sense to have runtime type information and some languages actually implement it, but it is debatable whether you need it and is a "Good Thing™".

Some useful info about type erasure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21843984/1417546

Comment: There is no problem with an array of `Void`, even at runtime. It's just another type: `Void[] a = new Void[1];` The type has the single member `null`.

Comment: When I said uninstantiable I referred to the fact that you cannot instantiate a `Void` object (`new Void()` rather than `new Void[]`, arrays of `Void`s are in fact acceptable).

Comment: However I clarified the concept in my answer, and also I incorrectly stated that it generated a runtime error, and it actually produces a compile time error (`the constructor is not visible`).