# Why am I unable to add the contents of a ArrayList into another ArrayList via the addAll method when the ArrayLists are both generically typed?

Tags: java, generics, collections, types, type-erasure

I'm trying to read a file to an `ArrayList` which has a unknown type declared via the wildcard character '?'. After using `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` to acquire a deserialized `Object` I then cast that `Object` as an `ArrayList<?>`. Then I attempt to add the elements of my casted `ArrayList<?>` into another `ArrayList<?>` via the `ArrayList.addAll(Collection)` method. However, my attempt to call `list.addAll(buffer)` fails with this exception message:

> No suitable method found for `addAll(ArrayList<CAP#1>)`

Why am I unable to add the elements of an `ArrayList<?>` into another instance of an `ArrayList<?>` via the `addAll()` method?

---

Here is the method that produces this exception:

```
public void readFile(ArrayList<?> list, String fileName) throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
    {
        ArrayList<?> buffer = (ArrayList<?>) ois.readObject();
        list.addAll(buffer);
        System.out.println("Added  to the customer list.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the type, but want to add to the list, it has to be `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: See [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

1. If the `type` are correlated :
   To be able to add a `List` to another, the first elements have to be same type of sub-type of the main `List`, you need :

   - to add `<T>` in the signature to tell that a generic is used
   - to use it in `ArrayList<T>` for the main one
   - to `ArrayList<? extends T>` for the sublist

   ```
   public <T> void readFile(ArrayList<T> list, String fileName) throws Exception {
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
       try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
           ArrayList<? extends T> buffer = (ArrayList<? extends T>) ois.readObject();
           list.addAll(buffer);
           System.out.println("Added  to the customer list.");
       }
   }
   ```

---

2. If type are random, change to

   ```
   ArrayList<Object> list
   ```

Comment: This isn't safe. You can call `readFile` with an `ArrayList<String>`, or an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and the same filename: at least one of those is going to fail (unless `ois.readObject()` returns an empty list, of course).

Comment: This answer should be edited to include type safety by use of `ObjectInputFilter` alongside `ObjectInputStream.setObjectInputFilter​(ObjectInputFilter)`. Then simply require callers to provide you either a single `Class` or `Class[]` instance, and use that to populate the filter's class name `String`s. Using these methods will cause the `ObjectInputStream` to throw an `InvalidClassException` if the filter returns `Status.REJECTED` upon reading a serialized object from the file.

Comment: Actually I will provide an alternative answer myself with a better method than `ObjectInputFilter` for this specific use case (we are only trying to deserialize a file containing one `Object` who can only validly be castable to one type, which we can simply check without `ObjectInputFilter`.

Answer (score -1):

## Generics or: How I Learned to Start Worrying and Hate Type Erasure

Your JVM is trying to determine what you meant when you gave it a certain series of [bytecodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203248/what-are-bytecodes-and-how-does-the-jvm-handle-them)/[literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210364/2446574) via the compiled source code. "Normally" everything is nicely declared using concrete class types like `String` or concrete primitive types such as `int`. For example, a value of `6` comes with some metadata that tells the JVM it is an `int` literal and not some other type. A series of bytes is meaningless on it's own; you need a way to tell the JVM what the binary numbers actually encode. The same binary value could represent an infinite number of ideas or states, so it is important that the type metadata is included to help make sense of it all. Without types the JVM wouldn't be able to tell a `char` with a value of `'a'` and a byte with a value of `0x61` apart. When you give a generic type, like the kinds used by implementations of the `List` interface (like the `ArrayList` you used) you are telling the compiler "this isn't a specific concrete type, it could be anything" (though using [`extends`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down) you can limit things a bit). Now, normally that might not be a problem, but due to backwards-compatibility issues I won't get into, dynamic types get erased away in a process called type erasure (look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918650/what-are-the-benefits-of-javas-types-erasure) for a very detailed explanation of the reasoning). The short and sweet answer which solves your problem is to simply take the extra complications of generic types into account and actively check and prevent casts which are not allowed. Thus type safety can mostly be achieved by checking generic type assignability manually instead of relying on automatic type safety like one might when using concrete types.

### Example Method

Here is a relatively type-safe version of your code(you will get a runtime error message in the worst case misuse scenario) with null checking and generic type bounding ( `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` use methods from the `Serializable` interface to implement their reading and writing of `Object` instances to the streams).

```
public static <OUTPUT extends Serializable, INPUT extends Serializable>
    OUTPUT getObjectFromFile(Class<INPUT> type, CharSequence fileName)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    final String filenameString = Objects.requireNonNull(fileName).toString();
    final Class<INPUT> inputType = Objects.requireNonNull(type);

    try (ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filenameString))) {
        final Object rawObject = ois.readObject();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final OUTPUT output = (OUTPUT) (rawObject == null ? null : inputType.cast(rawObject));

        return output;
    }

}

public static <DESIRED extends Serializable, STORED extends Serializable>
    boolean addArrayListFromFile(Collection<DESIRED> out, Class<STORED> type, CharSequence fileName)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final ArrayList<DESIRED> inList = getObjectFromFile(type, fileName);

    return inList != null && out.addAll(inList);
}
```

---

### More Details

These methods read serialized objects from a file with the specifics of type safety and file location specified via method parameters. The return value of the top-level method is actually a `boolean` indicating success or failure (`true` is success), but the actual data output is written into the `Collection` instance provided by the callee. Unlike a non-generic method, which can explicitly specify casts safely using the familiar `a = (a) b;` syntax, generic methods with generic types (like `DESIRED`,`STORED`,`INPUT` and `OUTPUT`) can't be sure exactly what type they will be handling. They lose this information about types through a process called type erasure.

Through type erasure developers and the JVM run-time lose the metadata about concrete types for types which are generified. As a result, the run-time and the developer are at the mercy of an input type being assignable to the required output type. Only the compiler could even possibly have provability for casts and it is not able to verify generic types in a general sense like it can concrete types. It is often the case that there is no type safety check possible until run-time. A `List<?>` at run-time might actually have been compiled and programmed as `List<String>` , but we can't determine the difference between two lists before run-time because the compiler is unable to maintain or determine the information we need to do so.

In addition to type erasure causing loss of type metadata, the compiler may also have incomplete knowledge of the program's run-time type graph. The potential for things like linking introducing new types that our current compiler doesn't recognize means we can never avoid unsafe casts on generic types with completely algorithmic approaches. In fact, there is no way to satisfy this type safety problem for generic types in a generalizable way as it amounts to a boolean satisfiability problem. However, there is somewhere else we can get the specific information on what types the caller of the method wanted and provided... the developer! Developers must specify explicit intent for generic types in order to provide type safety. By making the method caller (ultimately the developer) responsible for telling the run-time what to expect via passing a `Class<T>` instance to the code/method we can attempt to check generic types in such a way that we avoid a `ClassCastException`.

If we have a `List<T>` it simply becomes a `List` so we can no longer identify as differently typed from any other `List`. However, this isn't true for `Class<T>`, which we can exploit to pass the type metadata around the compiler and into the run-time (because `Class` objects store type information within the object graph instead of exclusively using Java's type system). It is, however, ultimately making the programmer responsible for providing the correct `Class<T>` for each method call. By making the run-time check types for validity the compiler's ability to detect type safety errors during compilation is mostly sacrificed for expressions utilizing generic types. You will no longer get warnings like "`int` cannot be cast as `String`" when you compile, instead you will just get an application exception or a cast safety verification failure that must be handled appropriately at run-time.

If you would like to play around with things and see what happens when you use this method I have created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/emabrey/a317a5b15bf60a38cb87a826bce0f38a) on GitHub containing a short little single file Class with a main method you can run as a little test program.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't know the type, but want to add to the list type-safely, it has to be `ArrayList<Object>`.

This is the only type which it is safe to add anything to. (I suppose it could technically be `ArrayList<? super Object>`; but there's nothing lower bounded by `Object` except itself).

Otherwise, you could call `readFile` with an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and then try to add, say, `String`s that you read from the `ObjectInputStream`. That would fail later, when you try to get an `Integer` out of the list, but the element is actually a `String`.

You *can't* use `ArrayList<T>` safely, for exactly the same reason: a method with this signature:

```
public <T> void readFile(ArrayList<T> list, String fileName) throws Exception
```

can be called like:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
readFile(strings, "filename");

ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
readFile(integers, "filename");  // <-- Note the same filename
```

Unless `filename` contains an empty list, at least one of these lists isn't type correct; thus, the method is not type safe. But it is insidiously type unsafe: this code would execute OK, but code (perhaps far away) would fail with a `ClassCastException` when it tries to retrieve an object from the list, and finds it is of the wrong type.